# cannot compile with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build

I'm trying to compile the project download from

> https://mkyong.com/tutorials/jsf-2-0-tutorials/
> using eclipe, when I run from command line
> `mvn clean compile pakage`
> everything goes well:

`C:\esempi\JSF2.0-hello-world-example-2.1.7\JavaServerFaces>mvn -version Apache Maven 3.8.8 (4c87b05d9aedce574290d1acc98575ed5eb6cd39) Maven home: C:\Users\a00569321\sw\apache-maven-3.8.8-bin\apache-maven-3.8.8 Java version: 1.7.0_13, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Users\a00569321\sw\jdk1.7.0_13\jre Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252 OS name: "windows 8", version: "6.2", arch: "x86", family: "windows"`

but when I try to compile using eclipse, I get:
[image]

and My eclipse configuration is:build path
[image]

Compile
[image]

and configuration
[image]

[image]

I've tried to change almost everything (java istallation, binary of maven, change compiler used by ecplipse);
I'm expecting to compile as i did using maven;

Comment: why on earth Java 1.7, if i may ask?

Comment: Some of the code is compiled using Java 8 (class version 52) you must use at least Java 8 at run it. Java 7 has been end of life for years, you should be using something more up to date.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError means compile version is higher than the actual runtime. When you compile from eclipse, it uses the java compliance level you configured from your IDE. When you compile using maven, it uses the java version from your pom.xml file. Class version 52 you encountered is Java 8, not 7.
Make sure your java (jdk not jre) version in your pom.xml file, under properties, is installed in your system. Once you set it, do `mvn dependency:sources dependency:resolve` then do a project update via the eclipse menu, then finally do `mvn clean install`

Something like

Take a look at this post [unsupportedclassversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: how can be possible? i do not have any version of java 1.8 istalled, in my pom there is (nothing in properties section):

 <build>
  <finalName>JavaServerFaces</finalName>

  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.7</source>
     <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

Comment: @fraaanz It is the maven code itself that is compiled with Java 8 - you can't run this maven with Java 7.

Comment: @greg-449. thanks but indeed if I use mvn clean compile package it works where mvn -version give me the output at the beginning of the post, How can be possible?

Comment: @fraaanz Maven is made up of lots of components some may be compiled with Java 7 and others with 8. The part you are trying to run requires Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Changing froom eclipse 2023_09 to 2019_09 it works well, because the maven embedded is an early version; So eclipse is not full compatibile with very old (very old :) ) version;
Hope some one can find it useful